# How to generate a x509 certificate chain of arbitrary length in Go

Tags: go, x509certificate, tls1.3

I'm trying to generate `x509` Certificate chains of arbitrary length, but failing miserably when attempting to verify it.

The verification fails with

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Here's the code that attempts to do it. It first generates a few root certificates which it then adds to a certificate pool which is used in verification

```
func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    count := 3

    rootKeys, err := makeRootKeys(count)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rootCerts, err := makeRootCerts(rootKeys)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rootPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    for _, rootCert := range rootCerts {
        rootPool.AddCert(rootCert)
    }

    for i := 1; i < count; i++ {
        chain, err := makeChain(rootKeys[i], i)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        opts := x509.VerifyOptions{
            Roots:     rootPool,
            KeyUsages: []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageAny},
        }

        leaf := chain[0]
        if opts.Intermediates == nil {
            opts.Intermediates = x509.NewCertPool()
            for _, intermediate := range chain[1:] {
                opts.Intermediates.AddCert(intermediate)
            }
        }

        if _, err := leaf.Verify(opts); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

The chain is built using the following code, which I suspect is where the problem lies but I can't seem to be able to to figure out where. The code attempts to create a chain of certificates of the given depth with the given root key.

```
type Key struct {
    priv crypto.PrivateKey
    pub  crypto.PublicKey
}

func makeChain(rootKey Key, depth int) ([]*x509.Certificate, error) {
    var (
        certs     = make([]*x509.Certificate, depth)
        parentKey = rootKey

        key  *ecdsa.PrivateKey
        cert *x509.Certificate
        err  error
    )

    for depth > 0 {
        if key, err = ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if cert, err = GenerateCACert(parentKey.priv, key.Public()); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        depth--
        certs[depth] = cert
        parentKey = Key{priv: key, pub: key.Public()}
    }

    return certs, nil
}
```

The full code is available in the [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/L9_HAbr2_N8). Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here which causes the certification verification to fail?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of debugging, I've realized a silly mistake I've made when specifying the `CommonName` of the issuer in the `GenerateCACert` that actually isn't displayed in the OG post.

```
func GenerateCACert(signer crypto.PrivateKey, trustedKey crypto.PublicKey) (*x509.Certificate, error) {
    subjectInfo := &certTemplateInfo{
        commonName: keyIDFromCryptoKey(trustedKey),
        isCA:       true,
    }

    issuerInfo := &certTemplateInfo{
        commonName: keyIDFromCryptoKey(signer),
    }


    return generateCert(signer.priv, trustedKey, subjectInfo, issuerInfo)
}
```

The `keyIDFromCryptoKey` func creates a fingerprint of the _public_key:

```
func keyIDFromCryptoKey(pubKey crypto.PublicKey) string {
    // Generate and return a fingerprint of the public key.
    // For an RSA key this should be:
    //   SHA256(DER encoded ASN1)
    // Then truncated to 240 bits and encoded into 12 base32 groups like so:
    //   ABCD:EFGH:IJKL:MNOP:QRST:UVWX:YZ23:4567:ABCD:EFGH:IJKL:MNOP
    derBytes, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pubKey)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    hasher := crypto.SHA256.New()
    hasher.Write(derBytes)
    return keyIDEncode(hasher.Sum(nil)[:30])
}
```

But I realized I was passing a *PRIVATE* key to it. Making sure the `signer`'s private key is used fixed the problem.

The full code is available in [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/wQNzVhLE_ut)

NOTE: some of this code originates in https://github.com/docker/libtrust